# How to make executable bin files accessible to Gnome?

Tags: gnome

I have several executable bin files in `~/bin` and I want to launch them using the Gnome environment. For example, pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows) key, typing the name in the search bar and then launch it.

How can I do this?  What directory will <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> look for?

And are they (search bar and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) the same one?

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same one.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> prompt will autocomplete and execute anything that is in the PATH environment variable. This means that to be able to execute your files in `~/bin` from there, you just need to set up the `PATH` variable in your `~/.bashrc` file, adding the `~/bin` path to it:

```
# just add this line to your bashrc
PATH=~/bin:${PATH}
```

However, the search bar that you get when pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> is a completely different thing. To get an application showing up there you must add it to the menu, using the `alacarte` program, check out the explanation in this question: [Adding custom applications to Gnome launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79583/adding-custom-applications-to-gnome-launcher)