# How can I make the tagspaces launch file work?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and open-source software in general. I have just started using Ubuntu 18.04 and other open-source software since June of this year. A couple of months ago, I installed tagspaces, a third-party application, on my Ubuntu 18.04 and was able to use it without much trouble.

Two days ago, I changed my hard drive for a new one with more memory, so I had to re-install all my software. For some reason, I'm unable to re-install Tagspaces. I've been downloading the `tar.gz`file corresponding to my system and extracted the file in my home folder. When I click on the `tagspaces`launch file, nothing happens. I have tried to make sure it has all the required permissions, but to no avail.

I'm not sure what to do and I'm a bit at a loss, as tagspaces is so useful for me!

Thank you in advance for your kind help!

Comment: Run the launcher file from the command line, and see if it gives you an errors.  GUI might eat those errors, and not give you error output, but the command line possibly won't.

Comment: Thank you for this information, but would you be able to explain how I do that? I have tried the line `sudo apt-get install tagspaces` and I get the following answer: `E: Impossible de trouver le paquet tagspaces`(sorry, my system is in French, but I guess, one can translate it as "E:impossible to find the tagspaces package"). I'm very, very beginner here!

Comment: Actually, I might have found a semi-solution: I have installed synaptic, re-started my computer and now, it seems I can use Tagspaces from the launcher file. Still, it doesn't appear in my list of software and the icon is a black screen with a red "forbidden" icon. It seems like the installation is not complete.

Comment: Given that you can launch TagSpaces now but the application is not visible in the list of softwares (and also showing a wrong icon after it's launched), you may create a menu item for the application manually to solve your issue. Follow this answer for a GUI way: https://askubuntu.com/a/79596/480481 (in place of command, click "browse" and select the executable launcher file for TagSpaces).

Comment: Alright, I tried, but I'm not sure what I accomplished. I still have this weird icon and it still doesn't appear in my software Ubuntu library. Each time I try to open Tagspaces, now, a terminal opens with the following message: `15:28:51.114: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`. So, I'm a bit at a loss!

Comment: I have tried to do something about this message and I found the following recommendations:
`sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk`
then, if it doesn't work, to use:
`sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk*`
or
`sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module`and so on. I have tried all of these, but I now get a blank terminal, with no message. And if close the terminal, Tagspaces closes as well. It's really weird! Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Alright. I have figured out what I did wrong. I downloaded the wrong installating file. I took the .tar.gz file, instead of the .deb file. Since both were listed as installation files for Ubuntu, I thought that any of them would work and had no idea why they were two. Also, I had already used .tar.gz files before, so I thought it was the right one, while I had understood that .deb was for Debian and that it was different from Ubuntu. Well, I still have tons to learn. But now it is working fine! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to get it working normally on Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

The problem: I was using Tagspaces fine on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. When Ubuntu 18.04LTS was released, I reformatted my HD and installed Ubuntu 18.04. Then I downloaded the latest version of Tagspaces and installed it with no issues. However, on clicking the tagspaces icon in the launcher, nothing happened.

The solution: I then tried running the app directly by opening a terminal and navigating my way to /usr/share/applications and then typing "tagspaces" to run the app. I received an error message that certain "shared libraries" were not able to be loaded and it indicated which dependency it was looking for. The solution was simply to use Synaptic package manager to install libgconf-2-4 which seems to be a dependency for Tagspaces.

Now Tagspaces runs normally from the launcher.

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong. I had downloaded the wrong file. I should have downloaded the .deb file and not the tar.gz one. It was a bit confusing for me. After I downloaded the right file, I was able to install it correctly and it is now functioning properly. Thank you all for your help!