# Create Custom Application Launcher in GNOME panel

Tags: gnome-shell

I've just installed 18.10 on a new machine and want to use the default GNOME desktop environment.

Before, I used GNOME Classic which has a task bar at the top of the screen with launchers. Right clicking on the task bar holding Alt brings up "Add to panel," then I have the option to create Custom Application Launcher. One of the options is to choose what command the new launcher should call.

I want to do this in my new GNOME (not Unity anymore?) environment, but don't know how.

Comment: I would recommend `alacarte` aka "Main Menu" GUI application, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/79596/480481

Comment: This doesn't add to the top panel bar (where the wifi, battery, speaker, etc icons are), it seems to add to the general applications, which can then be added to the side launcher. I would like little icons on the very top task bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)** GNOME shell extension.

> [It is] an icon taskbar for the Gnome Shell. This extension moves the dash into the gnome main panel so that the application launchers and system tray are combined into a single panel, similar to that found in KDE Plasma and Windows 7+. A separate dock is no longer needed for easy access to running and favorited applications.
>   [image]

You can place the panel at the top or bottom.

[image]

Refer to this for installing and managing GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)

You can add application launchers to the panel by "adding them to favourites" (refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/224010/480481)).

You can create a custom application launcher following this: [Adding custom applications to Gnome launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/79583/480481)

---

Another simpler alternative is the [**TaskBar**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/) extension, but unfortunately it seems its development has been stopped.