# No application launcher for scrcpy

Tags: android, 20.04, adb

I installed scrcpy snap in my ubuntu 20.04. but I can't find such application in my applications menu. I have to open the terminal for running it. Is it possible to create a launcher for running it? Please help

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and the output of he following 2 commands in Terminal: `ls /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` and `echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding custom applications to GNOME launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79583/adding-custom-applications-to-gnome-launcher)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `.desktop` file (you could use `nano` instead of `vim.tiny` or whatever you like):

```
sudo vim.tiny /usr/share/applications/scrcpy.desktop
```

Add the following contents.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=scrcpy
GenericName=scrcpy
Comment=Screen mirroring application
Exec=scrcpy %F
Icon=phone-symbolic
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=Development;GTK;
StartupNotify=true
```

It should be available just after creation.