# scrcpy shortcut

Tags: launcher, shortcuts

I installed scrcpy and created a shortcut, but the program only runs from the store, how do I create a shortcut with a working startup code ?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The code from here doesn't work...

[No application launcher for scrcpy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239353/no-application-launcher-for-scrcpy)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=scrcpy
GenericName=scrcpy
Comment=Screen mirroring application
Exec=scrcpy %F
Icon=phone-symbolic
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=Development;GTK;
StartupNotify=true
```

## When I click on a manually created shortcut... in the tray, the animation circle just turns and disappears.

When I enter a command from the terminal, I get this error:

```
:scrcpy
INFO: scrcpy 1.17 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
/usr/local/share/scrcpy/scrcpy-server: 1 file pushed. 2.8 MB/s (18570 bytes in 0.006s)
ERROR: Exception on thread Thread[main,5,main]
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.17"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at com.genymobile.scrcpy.Server.createOptions(Server.java:52)
    at com.genymobile.scrcpy.Server.main(Server.java:101)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:389)
```

## The program works only by clicking on the launch button in the GNOME store.

```
:scrcpy --help
Usage: scrcpy [options]

Options:

    --always-on-top
        Make scrcpy window always on top (above other windows).

    -b, --bit-rate value
        Encode the video at the given bit-rate, expressed in bits/s.
        Unit suffixes are supported: 'K' (x1000) and 'M' (x1000000).
        Default is 8000000.

    --codec-options key[:type]=value[,...]
        Set a list of comma-separated key:type=value options for the
        device encoder.
        The possible values for 'type' are 'int' (default), 'long',
        'float' and 'string'.
        The list of possible codec options is available in the
        Android documentation:
        <https://d.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat>

    --crop width:height:x:y
        Crop the device screen on the server.
        The values are expressed in the device natural orientation
        (typically, portrait for a phone, landscape for a tablet).
        Any --max-size value is computed on the cropped size.

    --disable-screensaver
        Disable screensaver while scrcpy is running.

    --display id
        Specify the display id to mirror.

        The list of possible display ids can be listed by:
            adb shell dumpsys display
        (search "mDisplayId=" in the output)

        Default is 0.

    --encoder name
        Use a specific MediaCodec encoder (must be a H.264 encoder).

    --force-adb-forward
        Do not attempt to use "adb reverse" to connect to the
        the device.

    --forward-all-clicks
        By default, right-click triggers BACK (or POWER on) and
        middle-click triggers HOME. This option disables these
        shortcuts and forward the clicks to the device instead.

    -f, --fullscreen
        Start in fullscreen.

    -h, --help
        Print this help.

    --legacy-paste
        Inject computer clipboard text as a sequence of key events
        on Ctrl+v (like MOD+Shift+v).
        This is a workaround for some devices not behaving as
        expected when setting the device clipboard programmatically.

    --lock-video-orientation value
        Lock video orientation to value.
        Possible values are -1 (unlocked), 0, 1, 2 and 3.
        Natural device orientation is 0, and each increment adds a
        90 degrees rotation counterclockwise.
        Default is -1 (unlocked).

    --max-fps value
        Limit the frame rate of screen capture (officially supported
        since Android 10, but may work on earlier versions).

    -m, --max-size value
        Limit both the width and height of the video to value. The
        other dimension is computed so that the device aspect-ratio
        is preserved.
        Default is 0 (unlimited).

    -n, --no-control
        Disable device control (mirror the device in read-only).

    -N, --no-display
        Do not display device (only when screen recording is
        enabled).

    --no-key-repeat
        Do not forward repeated key events when a key is held down.

    --no-mipmaps
        If the renderer is OpenGL 3.0+ or OpenGL ES 2.0+, then
        mipmaps are automatically generated to improve downscaling
        quality. This option disables the generation of mipmaps.

    -p, --port port[:port]
        Set the TCP port (range) used by the client to listen.
        Default is 27183:27199.

    --prefer-text
        Inject alpha characters and space as text events instead of
        key events.
        This avoids issues when combining multiple keys to enter a
        special character, but breaks the expected behavior of alpha
        keys in games (typically WASD).

    --push-target path
        Set the target directory for pushing files to the device by
        drag & drop. It is passed as-is to "adb push".
        Default is "/sdcard/".

    -r, --record file.mp4
        Record screen to file.
        The format is determined by the --record-format option if
        set, or by the file extension (.mp4 or .mkv).

    --record-format format
        Force recording format (either mp4 or mkv).

    --render-driver name
        Request SDL to use the given render driver (this is just a
        hint).
        Supported names are currently "direct3d", "opengl",
        "opengles2", "opengles", "metal" and "software".
        <https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER>

    --render-expired-frames
        By default, to minimize latency, scrcpy always renders the
        last available decoded frame, and drops any previous ones.
        This flag forces to render all frames, at a cost of a
        possible increased latency.

    --rotation value
        Set the initial display rotation.
        Possibles values are 0, 1, 2 and 3. Each increment adds a 90
        degrees rotation counterclockwise.

    -s, --serial serial
        The device serial number. Mandatory only if several devices
        are connected to adb.

    --shortcut-mod key[+...]][,...]
        Specify the modifiers to use for scrcpy shortcuts.
        Possible keys are "lctrl", "rctrl", "lalt", "ralt",
        "lsuper" and "rsuper".

        A shortcut can consist in several keys, separated by '+'.
        Several shortcuts can be specified, separated by ','.

        For example, to use either LCtrl+LAlt or LSuper for scrcpy
        shortcuts, pass "lctrl+lalt,lsuper".

        Default is "lalt,lsuper" (left-Alt or left-Super).

    -S, --turn-screen-off
        Turn the device screen off immediately.

    -t, --show-touches
        Enable "show touches" on start, restore the initial value
        on exit.
        It only shows physical touches (not clicks from scrcpy).

    -v, --version
        Print the version of scrcpy.

    -V, --verbosity value
        Set the log level (debug, info, warn or error).
        Default is info.

    -w, --stay-awake
        Keep the device on while scrcpy is running, when the device
        is plugged in.

    --window-borderless
        Disable window decorations (display borderless window).

    --window-title text
        Set a custom window title.

    --window-x value
        Set the initial window horizontal position.
        Default is "auto".

    --window-y value
        Set the initial window vertical position.
        Default is "auto".

    --window-width value
        Set the initial window width.
        Default is 0 (automatic).

    --window-height value
        Set the initial window width.
        Default is 0 (automatic).

Shortcuts:

    In the following list, MOD is the shortcut modifier. By default,
    it's (left) Alt or (left) Super, but it can be configured by
    --shortcut-mod (see above).

    MOD+f
        Switch fullscreen mode

    MOD+Left
        Rotate display left

    MOD+Right
        Rotate display right

    MOD+g
        Resize window to 1:1 (pixel-perfect)

    MOD+w
    Double-click on black borders
        Resize window to remove black borders

    MOD+h
    Middle-click
        Click on HOME

    MOD+b
    MOD+Backspace
    Right-click (when screen is on)
        Click on BACK

    MOD+s
        Click on APP_SWITCH

    MOD+m
        Click on MENU

    MOD+Up
        Click on VOLUME_UP

    MOD+Down
        Click on VOLUME_DOWN

    MOD+p
        Click on POWER (turn screen on/off)

    Right-click (when screen is off)
        Power on

    MOD+o
        Turn device screen off (keep mirroring)

    MOD+Shift+o
        Turn device screen on

    MOD+r
        Rotate device screen

    MOD+n
        Expand notification panel

    MOD+Shift+n
        Collapse notification panel

    MOD+c
        Copy to clipboard (inject COPY keycode, Android >= 7 only)

    MOD+x
        Cut to clipboard (inject CUT keycode, Android >= 7 only)

    MOD+v
        Copy computer clipboard to device, then paste (inject PASTE
        keycode, Android >= 7 only)

    MOD+Shift+v
        Inject computer clipboard text as a sequence of key events

    MOD+i
        Enable/disable FPS counter (print frames/second in logs)

    Ctrl+click-and-move
        Pinch-to-zoom from the center of the screen

    Drag & drop APK file
        Install APK from computer
```

The store collects the information and builds my server:

```
gnome-software-service.desktop[7737]: INFO: scrcpy 1.17 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
gnome-software-service.desktop[7788]: [100%] /data/local/tmp/scrcpy-server.jar
gnome-software-service.desktop[7788]: /usr/local/share/scrcpy/scrcpy-server: 1 file pushed. 8.6 MB/s (34930 bytes in 0.004s)
kernel: [ 
kernel: [
kernel: [
kernel: [
dbus-daemon[
dbus-daemon[
gnome-software-service.desktop[7790]: [server] INFO: Device:
gnome-software-service.desktop[7737]: INFO: Renderer: opengl
gnome-software-service.desktop[7737]: INFO: OpenGL version: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8
gnome-software-service.desktop[7737]: INFO: Trilinear filtering enabled
gnome-software-service.desktop[7737]: INFO: Initial texture: 1080x2336
```

Most likely, it should already be a program and not just a shortcut.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the output when you run the command `scrcpy` in a terminal (don't add a comment, edit your question instead). It may help to investigate the issue.