# How to use AppEditor to add app to app drawer?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-panel, appmenu

Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V VM

I have installed [AppEditor](https://github.com/donadigo/appeditor) as I am trying to add a file as an app but I can't get it to work. I have [directed it to the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJvz0.png) I want to add as an app but it won't launch when I click it in the app drawer. Alternatively, [how can I add it to favourites?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDwEX.png)

I found an alternative way to add the app to the app drawer/favourites, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248226/help-adding-app-to-favourites/1248328#1248328).

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly how to get AppEditor to function here, but what I CAN tell you is how to perform the same task in a different way. 
Here's a link to where I got the answer. 
https://askubuntu.com/a/257760
Run this command:
    `sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new`
It will bring up a menu you can use to add the application to the app drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome is lacking one utility like AppEditor it seems. Put in the fields, as [@florian-diesch](https://askubuntu.com/users/2369/florian-diesch) pointed out:

> ```
> Command Line = /usr/bin/java -jar jmol.jar
> Working Directory = /home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol-14.31.0-binary/jmol-14.31.0/
> ```

To put on favourites, if you're using Ubuntu with Gnome, you can press the Meta key to open the Overview and type the name of the program you want, after just move it to the dock.