# Help adding app to favourites

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-dock, gnome-panel, favorites

Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V VM

[I have tried following this but having no luck.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026528/adding-custom-programs-to-favourites-of-ubuntu-dock) The file shows in the app drawer but nothing happens when I click it. Here is what I have in my jmol.desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Jmol
Comment=Jmol-14.31.0
Exec=/home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol-14.31.0-binary/jmol-14.31.0/Jmol.jar
Icon=/home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol_icon_win.ico
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Jmol
```

The app works in the terminal by using `java -jar Jmol.jar` so is there a way to put that in the .desktop file and make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Path` key to change the working directory and run  `java -jar Jmol.jar`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Jmol
Comment=Jmol-14.31.0
Exec=java -jar Jmol.jar
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Jmol
Path=/home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol-14.31.0-binary/jmol-14.31.0/
Hidden=false
```

Comment: I have just tried that and still nothing is happening when I click on it, any other ideas?

Comment: What do you get if you run the command `python3 -c 'from gi.repository import Gio; Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename("jmol.desktop").launch(None, None)'` (one long line) in the folder where you saved the `jmol.desktop` file?

Comment: Ok sorry it did actually work, but only after I rebooted for some reason. But I still can't add it to favourites, even though the app shows in the app drawer and opens from there.

Edit: ok I can add it to favourites, just only in the app drawer, not after I've opened it. Also clicking the app on the taskbar opens another instance but its fine as long as I can open the app quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a short script that just executes the file properly, and add THAT to the app drawer?
Open a text editor, write
`java -jar /home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol-14.31.0-binary/jmol-14.31.0/Jmol.jar`
As the script, then save it as Jmol.sh.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Jmol
Comment=Jmol-14.31.0
Exec=/home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol-14.31.0-binary/jmol-14.31.0/Jmol.sh
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Jmol
Hidden=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Safer to first check the full path of the java application launcher `command -v java` or `command -pv java` to avoid aliases. It will return the full path, in my case /usr/bin/java. Also icons must be in one of [these formats](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html): PNG, XPM and SVG.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=Jmol
GenericName=3D Chemical Structure Viewer
Comment=Jmol-14.31.0
Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar jmol.jar
Path=/home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol-14.31.0-binary/jmol-14.31.0/
Icon=/home/adamch/Downloads/Jmol_icon_win.png
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Jmol
StartupNotify=true
```

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html

Once the file is correct (appears on the programs list, overview etc.), to put on favourites, if you're using Ubuntu with Gnome, you can press the Meta key to open the Overview and type the name of the program you want, after just move it to the dock.